# Random number generator that doesn't return values in range of all previously returned numbers?

Tags: python, random

My goal is to generate random numbers between (0, 500), but any new number has to be at a minimum 120 more/less than the previously returned value in the sequence. I am using Python in processing, which has the function - `random()` this accepts 2 arguments and returns a random number between them.

Comment: have you made any attempt at this yourself? show us the code

Comment: So you only want 4 or 5 numbers in total?

Comment: Is 500 inclusive in the list?

Comment: on what @ÉbeIsaac said is the number 498 valid, even though it's 2 away from 500 and not 120?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import random

def  genrandom():
    low_lim = 0
    high_lim = 0
    last = 0
    while True:
        low_lim = max(0, last - 120)
        high_lim = min(501, last + 120)
        rand_range = list(range(0, low_lim+1)) + list(range(high_lim,501))
        last = random.choice(rand_range)
        yield last
```

And use it like:

```
>>> rand_gen = genrandom()
>>> for i in range(10):
    print(next(rand_gen))

411
262
130
320
444
291
32
158
482
6
```

---

#### Edit:

And if you *really* can't get a value within 120 of *any previous value*, you'll exhaust your possibilities pretty quick:

```
def genrandom2():
    choices = list(range(0, 501))
    while choices:
        choice = random.choice(choices)
        yield choice
        low = max(0, choice - 120)
        high = min(501, choice + 120)
        for i in range(low, high):
            try:
                choices.remove(i)
            except ValueError:
                pass
    print("All done!")
```

In use:

```
>>> while True:
    print(next(rand_gen2))

455
168
296
9
All done!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#43>", line 2, in <module>
    print(next(rand_gen2))
StopIteration
```

Comment: 411 and 444 are not 120 apart

Comment: @depperm: They are not consecutive in order. The implementation is correct.

Comment: OOOHhhh, I missed that it had to be farther apart than *any* previous values...well, that certainly limits the quantity of number he can get ... and now I get @PM2 Ring's comment!

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac The OP didn't say anything about the numbers being consecutive. "any new numbers have to be at minimum 120 more/less than _any_ previously returned values"

Comment: @PM2Ring You're technically right, but I don't think the OP *intended* that meaning. I suggested an edit for clarification.

Comment: @Billy. yes your second edit has the behavior I wanted.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This should hopefully return a random number according to your constraints:

```
import random

def randGen(a, b, prev, mindev):
    n1 = a if (prev-mindev < a) else (prev-mindev)
    n2 = b if (prev-mindev > a) else (prev+mindev)
    choiceList = list(set(list(range(500+1))) - set(list(range(n1,n2+1))))
    return random.choice(choiceList)
```

In your case, a=0, b=500, and mindev=120. You ought to remember the prev. value each time when you call this function.

A demo run:

```
prev = 0
for i in range(10):
    prev = randGen(0, 500, prev, 120)
    print(prev)

391
159
36
186
15
398
4
296
101
498
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a brute-force solution, but it might work for you:

```
from random import randint

def _get_next_number(begin, end, max_diff, prev=None):
    if not prev:
       return randint(begin, end)

    while True:
        generated_number = randint(begin, end)

        if abs(generated_number - prev) < max_diff:
            continue

        return generated_number

def generate_numbers(low, high, max_diff, quantity):
    previous_generated_number = None

    for i in range(quantity):
        previous_number = _get_next_number(
            low,
            high,
            max_diff,
            previous_generated_number
        )

        yield previous_number

ten_random_numbers = generate_numbers(0, 500, 120, 10)
print(list(ten_random_numbers))
```

This should print something like this:

> [341, 138, 372, 153, 475, 174, 418, 66, 286, 125]

Comment: but any new numbers have to be at minimum 120 more/less than **any previously returned values**

Comment: Yes @depperm you are right, I have updated my answer. Thank you!